# numpy vectorize use on (2,) array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of `(m, 2)` and I want to transform it to shape of `(m, 1)` using a function below.

```
def func(x):
    if x == [1., 1.]:
        return 0.
    if x == [-1., 1.] or x == [-1., -1.]:
        return 1.
    if x == [1., -1.]:
        return 2.
```

I want this for applied on each `(2,)` vector inside the `(m, 2)` array resulting an `(m, 1)` array. I tried to use `numpy.vectorize` but it seems that the function gets applied in each element of a array (which makes sense in general purpose case). So I have failed to apply it.

My intension is not to use for loop. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Each condition has to be wrapped in `(x == [1., 1.]).all()`, then `np.vectorize(func, signature='(n)->()')(arr)` or `np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, arr)`. Both are slower than the comprehension `np.fromiter([func(x) for x in arr], dtype=float)`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np


def f(a, b):
    return a + b


F = np.vectorize(f)
x = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).T

print(F(*x))
```

Output:

```py
[3, 7, 11]
```

Comment: hi, your approach maybe right, but I don't think 1+2 = 5

Comment: Damn, you're right! Sorry, I've changed my answer.